# Understand Azure Websites Pay-As-You-Go

Tags: azure-web-app-service

I have a Pay-As-You-Go subscription on Azure and I created an "app" with intention to have a small blog. I didn't add or setup any other services or anything else.

[image]

It says "App Service Plan: Default1 (Free: 0 Small)"

What does it mean?

I'd like to understand how it works, how am I being charged?
Shouldn't be free considering I didn't add any service?
How do I know I am on the free tier?

Sorry if it sounds stupid

Comment: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/app-service/windows/

Comment: @4c74356b41 That doesn't help

Comment: Not sure I understand the question. Every web app has to reside in an App Service Plan (which range from "Free" to "A bunch of money" per month). Per your screenshot, you are using a Free-tier plan (which has all limitations documented, per @4c74356b41's link). And this answers your question on how you know you're on the free tier (as it tells you, in your screen shot). If you want the omitted features (like custom domain), or more performance, you'll need to upgrade to a paid tier.

Comment: What do you mean how it works, do you want to know the difference between plans?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Azure when you create a Web App, you need to have a server to host it on. To achieve that Azure creates a think called an App Service Plan (Think hosting server). The App Service Plan is what your billing is based on. Depending on the App Service Plan selected, you can host multiple sites on a single app service plan like you would on an on-premise server.

Azure App Service Plans come in the following tiers:

- F - Free - No cost but limited compute time (60 minutes a day)
- D - Shared - $9.67
- Basic - Starts at $55.80
- Standard - Starts at $74.40
- Premium

So from the looks of it, it says you are using a Free plan. To verify, go to the Azure Portal, navigate to your App Service. Then under that section got to App Service plan.

Which should give you the answer that you posted. So indeed you are using the Free tier of Azure. With that in mind, you app will only run 60 minutes a day, after that compute time has been used, your site will be shutdown. In addition realize that your site will "sleep" in between visitors causing the initial load to be affected.

Hope this helps.

More about costing can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/overview-hosting-plans#how-much-does-my-app-service-plan-cost).

Comment: FYI this is incorrect - a site is not limited to running "60 minutes a day" - the 60 minutes is 60 *CPU minutes* - the amount of time there is CPU activity for rendering/delivering site content. If a site is fairly lightweight (mostly static content, for example), and relatively low-traffic, the site could be running 24x7. Also, the site doesn't just sleep between visitors. The sleep happens when the application pool is recycled (which defaults to 20 minutes).

Comment: @DavidMakogon Please, clarify. For example, let's take Basic plan. Written that it costs 54.75 USD per month. If an app is really small and has only several visitors per month, would I still pay 54.75 or just a few bucks that CPU worked to deliver content to customers?

Comment: @AndriiViazovskyi - probably best to ask a new question (although pricing-specific questions are off-topic). But yes, you would pay whatever the price is listed at, and if it's not a serverless (consumption) based service, then you pay whether you use it or not (just like spinning up a vm and leaving it idle)